# flash messages in node.js with mustache template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mustache

I started out using the hackathon starter github repo [here](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter) for building out a node.js express app but soon realized I needed to change some things. I'm now using mustache but still would like to display the flash messages. It looks like {{messages.errors}}  contains some information but what gets displayed is [object, Object] when i console log this.

How can i see the contents of these objects?

The flash.mustache file looks like:

```
<script>
if ("{{messages.errors}}" != ""){
  console.log({{messages()}})
  console.log("error", {{messages()}}); // this line is seen as console.log("error",);
}
</script>
```

and flash is added to app.js as you would expect with

```
const flash = require('express-flash');
app.use(flash());
```

and in the routes flash is handled as you would expect (for example):

```
if (!user) {
  req.flash('errors', { msg: 'Account with that email address does not exist.' });
  return res.redirect('/forgot');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get message try it `messages.errors.msg`

or you can save message like this `req.flash('errors', 'Account with that email address does not exist.')`, then get message `messages.errors`